# How use the WebView FETCH api on android to call custom url

Tags: android, f#, android-webview, fetch-api

I'm looking to migrate the AJAX calls to the FETCH API. I can do this on android webview:

```
httpGet("data//app:customers")

function httpGet(theUrl)
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false ); // false for synchronous request
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```

And be intercepted by:

```
override this.ShouldInterceptRequest(view:WebView, request:IWebResourceRequest) =
    let rows = Customer.fakeData 1

    let st = Shared.jsonToStream(rows)
    new WebResourceResponse("application/javascript", "UTF-8", st)
```

However, If I try to use:

```
fetch("data//app:customers").then(function(data){return data})
```

I get the error:

```
VM44:1 Fetch API cannot load file:///android_asset/data//app:customers. URL scheme "file" is not supported.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't use Fetch API for file:// protocol. It just accepts HTTP protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I've just solved this for our nativescript-plugin`@nota/nativescript-webview-ext`.

The native 'Fetch API' doesn't allow you to request anything other than `http` and `https`.

The polyfill from "whatwg-fetch" doesn't have that restriction.

To use the polyfill you need to remove the native function first by setting it to null before loading the polyfill.

You can get it from https://www.npmjs.com/package/whatwg-fetch or https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/whatwg-fetch@3.0/dist/fetch.umd.min.js